# How to create a custom page or template for WooCommerce Endpoints?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

I am building a website using WooCommerce. I am trying to create a custom page for my-account/payment-methods/ endpoint that comes with WooCommerce. I cannot edit that specific page/endpoint. Does anyone know how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

WooCommerce endpoints can be edited under WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced